# Optimise large UITableView load Core Data

Tags: performance, core-data

in my app, I fetch a list of messages from a web service and store them with Core Data.

Over time, the amount of messages grows, and since I want to have all of them offline to be searchable within my app, that's by design.

However, the larger the amount of messages in my database, the longer it takes to display them in a UITableView. Obviously, I show a spinner, but I think there should be a solution that results in a better user experience.

I tried the following:

1. Load all messages from database
2. Sort them
3. Display the top 10 in
   TableView
4. Load and Display ALL of them in TableView

As a result, the Tableview loads faster, but then gets stuck for a short while loading the full batch

One of the problems I have, is that the messages are not necessarily stored in the order that they need to be displayed, hence the sorting

Would any of you have a suggestion on how to approach this?

Comment: Can you sort as part of the fetch, rather than sorting after the fetch?  Are you using NSFetchedResultsController?  Have you tried fetchBatchSize?